# js calling a function with a nested unnamed function and getting a value from it

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

```
function myFunction(a,callback){}
myFunction(a, function(test){c = 'result';});
console.log('value c '+c);
```

Any ideas on how to get in the third line to get the value с?
I tried to use:

```
var c = myFunction(a, function(test){c = 'result';});
```

but it did not help

Comment: Your `myFunction()` does not do anything. The function passed in the call to it will not exist after that statement. If you would explain what you're trying to do you might get an answer, but the direct answer to your question as written is that it does not make any sense, and no there is no way.

Comment: `myFunction()` needs to call the callback **synchronously**, then you should see the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

myFunction needs to do something with the arguments being passed.

In my answer I'm running the callback function and returning's return value. and in your anonymous function I'm returning the value instead of setting the value of a variable.

```js
function myFunction(a,callback){
  return callback();
}
const a = "";
const c = myFunction(a, function(){return 'result';});
console.log('value c '+c);
```

Comment: You don't need `.call()`; `callback()` suffices.

Comment: @Unmitigated, thank you I removed it. I was working on using it for something but decided not to, just forgot to remove it.